# Looping in javascript to disable fields

Tags: javascript, loops

I am kinda new to java and javascript. I would like to know how I can loop the following script so that I will not need to create so many lines of code. This script is used to disable fields and enable them only when the user selects the check box.

```
<script>
 function start() {
  form1.s_Name.disabled = true;
  form1.r_Name.disabled = true;
  form1.s_Address.disabled = true;
  form1.r_Address.disabled = true;
  form1.s_Postal.disabled = true;
  form1.r_Postal.disabled = true;
  form1.s_City.disabled = true;
  form1.r_City.disabled = true;
  form1.s_Email.disabled = true;
  form1.r_Email.disabled = true;
  form1.s_Phone.disabled = true;
  form1.r_Phone.disabled = true;
}

onload = start;
function chgtx() {
 form1.s_Name.disabled = !form1.chkChange.checked;
 form1.r_Name.disabled =!form1.chkChange.checked;
 form1.s_Address.disabled = !form1.chkChange.checked;
 form1.r_Address.disabled = !form1.chkChange.checked;
 form1.s_Postal.disabled = !form1.chkChange.checked;
 form1.r_Postal.disabled = !form1.chkChange.checked;
 form1.s_City.disabled = !form1.chkChange.checked;
 form1.r_City.disabled = !form1.chkChange.checked;
 form1.s_Email.disabled = !form1.chkChange.checked;
 form1.r_Email.disabled = !form1.chkChange.checked;
 form1.s_Phone.disabled = !form1.chkChange.checked;
 form1.r_Phone.disabled = !form1.chkChange.checked;
 }
```

I think form the code you can see that only `form1.s_` and `form1.r_` and `!form1.chkChange.checked;` are fixed and repeating.

Can you please advise me on how I can convert this code into a loop style to be more efficient?

Comment: javascript is not java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over your fields like this :

```
var inputFields = form1.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    nbIF = inputFields.length;

for(var iIF = 0; iIF < nbIF; iIF++) {
    if(inputFields[iIF].name.substring(0, 2) === "s_" ||
       inputFields[iIF].name.substring(0, 2) === "r_")
        inputFields[iIF].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

and the same for the other function...

```
function chgtx() {
    for(var iIF = 0; iIF < nbIF; iIF++) {
        if(inputFields[iIF].name.substring(0, 2) === "s_" ||
           inputFields[iIF].name.substring(0, 2) === "r_")
            inputFields[iIF].disabled = !form1.chkChange.checked;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All the fields are either textboxes or text areas and not checkbox. There is only one checkbox to enable and disable edits.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, it will disable all elements of form except check box

Javascript

```
function validate()
{
    var dis = document.getElementById('myform');
    var ele = dis.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
    {
         if(ele[i].getAttribute("type") != "checkbox")
         {
                 ele[i].disabled = true;

         }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think this will work. A small question. Is there a readonly attribute. Cause if i use the disabled attribute data is not being saved into my db.

Comment: @user1571494 Even it is disabled it can have value assigned by javascript, and is it is sent to server it will modify your db

Comment: How is it possible. Can you advise.

Comment: can i assign readonly attribute to the fields. Html is done via readonly="readonly" way. but via javascript how to do it.

Comment: @user1571494 you can change value of any disabled input element, disabled means it wont be editable by click or any user event but can be modified by javascript. to modify or read you use .value property

Comment: @user1571494 No you can't, value of an input element can always be changed by javascript. so if you want to make it read only then dont modify it

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to enable/disable only some fields, but not all, you can use an array like this:

```
<script>
var fieldsToToggle = ["Name", "Address", "Postal"]

function setDisabledStatus(fields, mode) {
  var i;
  var l = fields.length;
  var fieldRoot;
  var form = document.getElementById('myform');

  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    fieldRoot = fields[i];
    form["s_" + fieldRoot].disabled = mode;
    form["r_" + fieldRoot].disabled = mode;
  }
}

setDisabledStatus(fieldsToToggle, true);
</script>
```